# Change the order in ModernCV banking

Tags: moderncv

When using classic theme vs using banking theme, the classic highlights the job title whereas banking highlights the employer.

[image: Classic]

[image: Banking]

How do I make it so that banking highlights the job title instead of the employer, and comes in the order of job title and then employer like in classic theme.

The MWE is the following: (change the style from classic to banking for the change in the order of job title and employer}

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

 \moderncvstyle{classic}
 %\moderncvstyle{banking}
 \moderncvcolor{blue}
 \usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

 \name{John}{Doe}
 \title{Resumé title}
 \address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
 \phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
 \phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
 \phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}

\begin{document}

 \section{Experience}
 \subsection{Vocational}
 \cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
 }
 \end{document}
```

Comment: The obvious solution is to swap all the field entries around. I can swap all the fields around to get the effect I want but I have to change all the entries. Maybe there is a simpler one-line solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%   
      {\bfseries #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\bfseries #2}\\%
      {\itshape #4} & {\itshape #5}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\\\vbox{\small#7}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Banking Executive}
\address{Address line 1}{Address line 2}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{Email}
\social[linkedin]{linkedin}
\social[github]{github}
\quote{Some quote}

\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%   
      {\bfseries #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\bfseries #2}\\%
      {\itshape #4} & {\itshape #5}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\\\vbox{\small#7}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{Jan/2010 -- Feb/2012}{Jobtitle}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should just update `\cventry` to suit your needs. This is `\cventry` from the `banking` style:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
      {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} \\%
      {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\\\vbox{\small#7}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

Here is `\cventry` from the `classic` style:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

Adjustments are possible via [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) due to the optional argument of `\cventry`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}

\newcommand{\employerfont}{\slshape}
\newcommand{\jobfont}{\bfseries}
\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch
% \xpatchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{\bfseries #4}{\jobfont #3}{}{}% Swap Employer for Job
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{\itshape #3}{\employerfont #4}{}{}% Swap Job for Employer

\begin{document}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
}
\end{document}
```